# Error while configuring VKD3D

Tags: command-line, wine, compiling, vulkan

I'm following these steps (https://github.com/d3d12/vkd3d/blob/master/INSTALL), but after I running `./configure` in terminal, the routine ends prematurely with `configure: error: vulkan.h not found.` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install the corresponding -dev package by:

```
sudo apt-get install libvulkan-dev
```

And also please note that VKD3D is [packaged in Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/vkd3d), so you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libvkd3d-dev vkd3d-demos
```

and then reboot, and check it by running `gears-vkd3d` demo.